# Why this === window is false in JavaScript scope safety constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, window, this

my code is:

```
(function(){
    var test=function(){
        if(this === window)
            return new test();
    }

    test.prototype.play = function(){
        alert("Hello");
    };

    window.Test=test;
})();

window.onload=function(){
    Test().play();
};
```

this can work well in `IE9+` `firefox` `chrome`,but in `ie 6/7/8` ,an error show in `Test().play();` ,who can tell me why?

the error information is:

[image]

Comment: If that line causes an error, it's probably because `window.Test=test;` wasn't executed.  Have you tried adding a try/catch block around `Test().play();`?

Comment: You may well find the answer in [Named function expressions demystified](http://perfectionkills.com/named-function-expressions-demystified/).

Comment: *What* error do you get? While ugly code, nothing is jumping out at me as being immediately wrong.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J6y6G/

Comment: @pst the error information is "undefined" is null not an object

Comment: @artwl Exactly *which* expression evaluates to `undefined`? `Test`, `Test()`, `Test().play`, other? Work the problem backwards.

Comment: @pst `window.onload=function(){document.write(Test());//undefined};`

Comment: @artwl I do not believe it is possible for the posted code to return `undefined` from evaluating `Test()`; however, perhaps sometime *before* `unload` occurs something *else* modifies/assigns to `window.Test`? (I was reading that last comment as "undefined is written to the document/output"). Can you create a jsfiddle test-case (or use jfriend00's) and see if this issue can be reproduced in in IE7? IE8? IE9 in IE7/IE8-mode using said jsfiddle?

Comment: @pst i test [http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J6y6G/](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J6y6G/) use IETest,i get same error:picture is [error picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dH6Tr.png)

Answer (score 0):

IE has some quirks with function expressions, consider (not tested in IE 8 since I don't have it at the moment):

```
(function(global){

    function test() {
        if (this === global)
            return new test();
    }

    test.prototype.play = function(){
        alert("Hello");
    };

    global.Test = test;

})(this);

window.onload = function(){
    Test().play();
};
```

An alternative test is:

```
    if (!(this instanceof Test))
```

Comment: But when would `window !== global`?

Comment: use `this === global` i get the same error,use `if (!(this instanceof Test))` is ok

Comment: (I really don't see how [named] function expression apply here at all.)

Comment: @artwl Curious, what happens when using `window.Test().play()`? (With the `this === window` approach.)

Comment: @pst 'window.Test()' is null or not an object

Comment: @pst—there was a section on quirks, I didn't have time to go over it again and thought it might have covered some IE quirks with function expressions. There are cases in IE where `window !== window` (i.e. there appears to be two different window objects) but I can't dig them up right now.